# C segfault using long integers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I don't understand why this code compiles and then segfaults:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long int gcd(unsigned long int, unsigned long int);
unsigned long int lcm(unsigned long int, unsigned long int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    unsigned long int n = 1L;
    for (i = 2; i < 21; i++) {
        n = lcm(n, i);
    }
    printf("%ld\n", n);
    return 0;
}

unsigned long int gcd(unsigned long int a, unsigned long int b) {
    if (a == b) return a;
    if (a > b) return gcd(a - b, b);
    return gcd(a, b - a);
}

unsigned long int lcm(unsigned long int a, unsigned long int b) {
    return abs(a * b) / gcd(a, b);
}
```

Are those `unsigned long`s even necessary? I also noted that if I change that `21` to a `18` it gives the correct result. The code is meant to find the LCM of all the numbers from `1` to `20`.

Running it in `gdb` gives:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400643 in gcd (a=7536618, b=18) at p5.c:19
19    if (a > b) return gcd(a - b, b);
```

Comment: Did you tried to attach debugger and get a stacktrace? My guess is that problem is too deep recursion in `gcd()`

Comment: @myaut Thanks, I run it with `gdb`. I'll edit the question with the result.

Comment: It looks like you are right. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: perhaps "warning: Source file is more recent than executable." is not a good edit

Comment: @EdHeal Ah well I was just changing the value `21` to see what happened, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overflowing the stack. Which is a shame, because that should be easily optimized as tail recursion, full recursion is extremely overkill for this. Using the proper optimization levels in any modern compiler (cl, gcc, icc) should get rid of the segfault.

Luckily writing this iteratively is trivial as hell:

```
unsigned long gcd(unsigned long a, unsigned long b) 
{ 
  while(a != b)
    if(a > b)
       a -= b;
    else 
       b -= a;

  return a;
}
```

Comment: @myaut, when lines are this short all the spaces make it look less readable imo. Up to you all though.

Comment: when most of code follows style with "spaces-around-operators" (i.e. PEP-8, Linux Kernel), it makes it less readable. And it breaks in-brain tokenizer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Due to how the *stack* and how they work, there's a limit on how deep function calls can be nested, depending on how much local state they keep.

For extremely imbalanced arguments, implementing `gcd` by repeated subtraction requires a *lot* of iterations, and so your recursion goes *way* to deep. You need to either change the implementation (e.g. make it iterative), or change the algorithm (e.g. compute remainders instead of differences).

You could increase the stack size, but that is wasteful of memory and the larger size will run eventually run out too with larger inputs.